# How do I get a SpringBatch Integration test to load my application properties?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have the following Spring Batch test in my `src/test/java`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes= MyBatchConfig.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
                                DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@ActiveProfiles("local-test")
public class MyIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Autowired
    private JobRepositoryTestUtils jobRepositoryTestUtils;

    @Test
    public void testJob() {
       ...
    }
```

I define my `test/resources/application-local-test.yml`:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: "test"
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:TEST_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;IGNORECASE=TRUE;
    username: sa
    password: pwd
  jpa:
    open-in-view: true
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
      ddl-auto: create
  h2:
    console: enabled

cloud:
  aws:
    s3:
      bucket: testBucket
```

and in my main application, a SpringBatch Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class ImportProjectsBatchConfig {

    public static final String JOB_NAME = "myJob";

    private String s3BucketName;

    public ImportProjectsBatchConfig(
            @Value("${cloud.aws.s3.bucket}")
                    String s3BucketName) {
        this.s3BucketName = s3BucketName;
    }

    @Bean
    public String s3BucketName() {
        return s3BucketName;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleStepBuilder<WebProject, WebProject> simpleStepBuilder(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
            ItemProcessor itemProcessor, ItemWriter itemWriter,
            MyErrorItemListener errorItemListenerSupport) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get(JOB_NAME).<WebProject, WebProject>chunk(chunkSize)
                .processor(itemProcessor).listener((ItemProcessListener) errorItemListenerSupport)
                .writer(itemWriter).listener((ItemWriteListener) errorItemListenerSupport);
    }

}
```

When I try to run the integration test my application-local-test.yml is not getting picked up:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'cloud.aws.s3.bucket' in value "${cloud.aws.s3.bucket}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:178)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried moving `test/resources/application-local-test.yml` to `main/resources/application-local-test.yml`?

Comment: That does not fix it- thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Is there a reason you're setting `spring.profiles.active` in `test/resources/application-local-test.yml`?  Do you have another `test` profile that you are using with `local-test`?

Comment: no- just an unfortunate habit of copy and paste from other projects. Removing it does not fix the issue

Comment: Which version of spring boot are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same situation that I cannot load the application.yaml while using `@SpringBatchTest` to write an integration test.

I ended up adding **`@SpringBootTest`** to solve the problem.

According to the [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/test/context/SpringBatchTest.html), @SpringBatchTest register beans like JobLauncherTestUtils, JobRepositoryTestUtils...etc for the test.

However if we want to enable spring boot functionalities like loading application properties, adding @SpringBootTest seems to be a way. ([document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html))